# How to set up an Apache Web Server in WebStorm?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver, webstorm

I've been trying to set up an Apache Web Server in WebStorm (a JetBrains IDE) in order to test my website and use the `.htaccess` configuration. However, after searching through documentation, I was unable to find an answer.

I've created my `.htaccess` file, but it needs an Apache Web Server to work. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: 1) Do you have the Apache installed in your computer? You would obviously need it. 2) So you want to configure WebStorm so it opens your files/URLs that your Apache is serving? Did I get this right? If so -- you need to look at the Deployment. There you can make one (e.g. "In Place" type if the files are already located in the right place) and then mark it as Default for this project -- now WebStorm will use that URL instead of the simple built-in web server that is used when no URL is provided. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/deploying-applications.html